# AWS CloudFront doesn't find my ELB as an origin in Mumbai region

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudfront

I have my infra setup in AWS singapore region. Now I want to migrate to Mumbai region.

I have launched 2 EC2 instances in AWS Mumbai region and deployed my web application and kept behind ELB which is working fine. If I create my Cloudfront which shows all other regions origin servers(especially from singapore in my case) not the ELB origin which I have created in Mumbai region.

I felt strange that does AWS Cloudfront support for origin servers in mumbai region yet or not?

I see CloudFront also supports in Mumbai region according the [AWS Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-open-aws-asia-pacific-mumbai-region/?sc_channel=sm&sc_campaign=launch_marketing_b5b3b2f8&sc_publisher=tw_go&sc_content=aws_mumbai_is_open&sc_country=global&sc_geo=global&adbsc=social_launches_20160628_63257556&adbid=z12kxjaqinuixtqxw04cc5fwdzalettx1ro0k&adbpl=gp&adbpr=100017971115449920316)

Please let me know if anyone have experiences the same. Thanks

Comment: Assuming you have validated that the balancer is working, then there might be an integration issue there that impacts the console, but even if there is, it should make no difference in actual operations of a distribution. Try simply pasting or typing the hostname of the balancer into the box.  The origin server can be any valid hostname, whether from an AWS service or not.

Comment: Yes you are absolutly right, there might be an integration issue. I have copy pasted CNAME of elb and then its worked.  Thanks